# Is mysqli_multi_query the same as multiple calls to mysqli_query?

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

The documentation of [`mysqli_multi_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) and [`mysqli_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) doesn't say if calling `mysqli_multi_query` is the same as calling `mysqli_query` multiple times.

Does anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 2):

No. mysqli_multi_query is asynchronous, it will send all queries to a database server but return only the first result immediately. Therefore to check the result of all other queries you will need some additional code. Whereas to run a set of mysql_query() you dont't need any additional code, but just use the every query's result right away.

That said, both functions have a very limited use. The only application for mysqli_multi_query is to run some pre-written sql dumps. mysql_query() has a very limited use too, as there are not so much queries that do not accept variable data. And for such queries you must use **mysqli_prepare()** instead.

Comment: mysqli_query is also asynchronous when called with `MYSQLI_ASYNC`. The first result returned by mysqli_poll+mysqli_reap_async_query is the first that is ready. The control is also given for each query run asynchronously since the thread_id is available for each one. Would this make mysql_query better than mysqli_multi_query?

Comment: I don't understand your criteria for comparing these functions so I can't tell. All I can tell mysqli_multi_query will wait for the first query result but async mysqli_query will not. I don't get the idea of all that comparison though